# Automatization of third party libraries in python with PowerShell or CMD

Tags: python, powershell, cmd, subprocess

If I want to run my Python 3.8 program in Windows 10, I have to firstly load below commands in PowerShell:

```
PS> cmd
CMD> call [somePath]/environmentSettingScript.bat
CMD> set Path=%Path%;D:[someOtherPath]\win64
```

After that, I am able to run Python in the same window (still CMD running in PS) and load my third party libraries.

```
CMD> python
>>> from thirdPartyLibrary import something
```

or

```
CMD> python programThatUseThirdPartyLibrary.py
```

Of course, it works also, if I make `call` and `set` procedures from first snippet directly in CMD. Nevertheless, I don't like such kind of solutions. I want to automatize this procedure, in programThatUseThirdPartyLibrary.py code directly with Spyder IDE usage. To do this I try write something like that:

```
import subprocess

pipe = subprocess.Popen(r"cmd \c call [somePath]/environmentSettingScript.bat \c set Path=%Path%;D:[someOtherPath]\win64", 
                        stdin = subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stdout = subprocess.PIPE, 
                        stderr = subprocess.PIPE, 
                        encoding='utf8',
                        shell=True)
stdout, stderr = pipe.communicate()
print("No stderr" if pipe.returncode == 0 else "Some stderr")

from thirdPartyLibrary import something
```

Unfortunately, `stdout` shows only the information about loading first line of `cmd` command:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1697]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

D:\[workDir]>
```

and it looks like, that the rest of commands stuck in the pipe. I am quite confused, because `print()` and `stderr` shows that, everything goes ok - but `import` at the end of the script fails with error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named thirdPartyLibrary
```

Comment: Was `pip` used to install the third-party libraries?

Comment: Nope, they are not available in pypi, conda etc.